# Highlight current week of Datepicker in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

How we can highlight all dates of current week by changing the background color in Xamarin forms?

Comment: I'm not sure it would be possible without a custom renderer.

Comment: Can you please just elaborate how can i do this.I want to change background of current week in xamarin forms.